# PHP Database Session writing old data back in after it has changed intermittently

Tags: php, sql-server, session, iis

I have this strange issue that has manifested itself. 
The setup:
Windows 2008 R2
PHP 5.4
IIS 7
MSSQL Server
2 Servers load balanced, session in database

This is a health application, when a patient is selected their data is stored in the session, when a new patient is selected the old patient's data is unset and the new patients is saved. Intermittently the last patients data will be overwritten.

I have added some output to the database write function for the session and can see the current patients data being written and then in the middle of nowhere I can see the old data being written back in. I have no idea where it is getting this data from and another strange thing is that it is happening on one of the servers.

I even built a new server and it is happening on this too, would be most grateful for any help.

I have been through the code with a fine tooth comb, there is only one place where the patient data gets written and I output to the log every time that happens. I output every time the session gets written to and a few other significant events. The patient data changes in the middle of a block of session writes

Comment: Are you 100% sure that there is no problem with your code? I would go look for  it first.

Comment: I have been through it with a tooth comb, there is only one place where the patient data gets set and I output to the log every time that happens. I output every time the session gets written to and a few other significant events. The patient changes in the middle of a block of session writes.